# Save data and repopulate form without creating a column for each field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a situation where I need to collect data from a user, save the data, and later be able to go back and view the data.  In this case it is a survey.  Normally I would create a model and put in some validations and it would be pretty straightforward.

But in this case the questions change so frequently that if I did that I might find myself writing new migrations and performing all kinds of maintenance constantly.  And since all we really want is the data itself, it occurred to me that I should just make a model that has an id field and a form_data field and just stick whatever the params are into that form_data field.  That way all I have to do is change the view and not mess with the model at all.

But later if I wanted to edit the data in the survey, how would I populate the form fields? The goal is to only change the view whenever my boss wants to add new questions.

P.S. I would prefer not to use Surveyor for this task since I'd like to be able to do some things that aren't easily don ein Surveyor from what I can tell.

So this is what it might look like

```
SurveySubmissions
  id : integer
  form_data: string

SurveySubmissions.find(1).form_data
   "name":"Kevin"
   "gender":"Male"
   "favorite_color":"blue"
```

Comment: I haven't written any code.  I'm trying to figure out how I would do something like this, or if there is a better approach than what I've proposed here.

Comment: Even if there's no code yet, can you define the models as you see them at the moment? It's not clear what form_data represents. Is it the form questions, or answers ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best choice is to save the form fields into the database and then use javascript to repopulate the form when editing.  So I pull all the field values into a variable and then use JQuery.each to populate the fields.

```
surveySubmissionData = {"incident_id":"2013BaconSupreme",
    "_confirmed":"No",
    "_date_began":"2/26/2013"}

// Put some code here that loops through the surveySubmissionData 
// and populates the form.

jQuery.each(surveySubmissionData, function(i, val) {
    $("#" + i).val(val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PostgreSQL you can take a look at Hstore. A nice starting point is this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/345-hstore (pro episode, so it requires payment).
It allows you to store all question/answer pairs in single database column.

You can also serialize your data into single database column as json/yml and use virtual attributes on your model to make it easy to populate form fields (Railscast episode about virtual attributes: http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised, there is also old episode for free)

Another solution (and my favorite) is to use MongoDB + Mongoid and its dynamic attributes.
It can be the best solution if you didn't start coding yet.

Comment: I was thinking that MongoDB is the right way to go on this.  I can totally see how it would make sense since each survey is basically a document and it can change frequently.  I guess I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to repopulate the form if someone wants to edit a survey later.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you :

User Model

```
has_many :surveys
```

Survey Model

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :questions
```

Submissions Model

```
has_many :questions
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :survey
```

Question Model

```
has_many :answers
polymorphic => belongs_to "survey and submissions"
```

Answer Model

```
belongs_to :submission
belongs_to :question
```

and on top of this u can build relations and other stuff you require as per your requirements